# Debugger showing wrong values for float

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, debuggervisualizer

I noticed that some float variables are being shown wrong in Visual Studio 2017 debugger, although the internal value is right, that is, it is only wrong in the debug view.

For example:

```
obj_carro.vel1000rpm.push_back(stof(parte[2].substr(0, pos)));

cout << stof(parte[2].substr(0, pos)) << endl;
cout << obj_carro.vel1000rpm[obj_carro.vel1000rpm.size() - 1]  << endl;
```

It shows the correct value:

```
9.9
9.9
```

But VS 2017 debugger shows:

```
9.89999962  float
```

What is wrong?
How to solve this?

Update: the `cout` output rounds to 6 decimal places after the point. This should be an answer, but the question is on hold...

Comment: No, they are being shown "right" in the debugger, and truncated  when output in your program. The answer is to fix the formatting in your program, if you want the "right" answer, and to read up on how floating point variables are implemented - start at http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The real question is why the `cout <<` result is not same as what OP sees in the debugger? Is `cout <<` rounding somehow?

Comment: @Arkady, yes it is.

Comment: @Arkadiy iostreams' default precision is 6 digits

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I found some references to that, yes. Where is it specified?

Comment: @Arkadiy in the iso c++ standard presumably. I don't know the standard and don't care to look for it, if you'd like to be sure you can ask a separate question and tag `language-lawyer` for an appropriate answer

Comment: Reference to default of `6` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision  also here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: So the answer to this question is: *default precision for float is 6, here is why*. How is `[language-agnostic]` "Floating point math is broken" a duplicate?

Comment: @Arkadiy Because the question simplifies to: _"why can't the computer hold 9.9 exactly"_.

Comment: @RichardCritten, I am arguing that it's not the case here, that this question is about rounding in `cout`. Of course I may be wrong. Maybe OP should clarify, if he wants the question reopened.

Comment: Added another answer to the dup. @RichardCritten, let me know if you'd rather own it.

Comment: The fact is, I've learned that a simple command like `float f = 9.9` will never store exactly `9.9` and that's sad, although the huge text indicated by @Neil Butterworth has millions of technical reasons for it.
I also learned that `cout` and other commands round float result, never showing their exact value.
But we have to adapt to reality and deal with it.

Comment: @RogérioDec At least the cout precision can be adjusted.